# React Router+Redux: how to fetch prior to dispatching a route change, but also respond to the navigation events?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-router-redux

I'm learning to use React + Redux + `react-router-redux`. The project is a toy project, and there are only two routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={ItemList} />
<Route path="/:id/" component={ItemView} />
```

First, I have implemented basic operation: when user clicks on `ItemList`, I call `dispatch(push(`/${id}/`))`. Then, using `<Router onChange={...}>` I detect the navigation and dispatch an action to fetch item's data from server. When the data arrives I can finally put it in my state and `ItemView` updates from just saying "Loading..." to a proper item display.

However, I want things shiny and fancy. On click, I want to start fetching data but *keep old UI* (the item list) until the data arrives, and only then - having the data - quickly switch the route. Just like GitHub or GitLab do. So I had researched a bit, threw in `redux-thunk`, `redux-promise-middleware` and `react-redux-loading-bar` and wrote some code.

In the list component, I have what's essentially `onClick={dispatch(getItem(id))}` where `getItem` is:

```
export function getItem(id) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return dispatch({
            type: GET_ITEM,
            payload: new Promise(resolve => {
                fetch(`/${id}/?json`)
                    .then(response => resolve(response.json()))
            })
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch(push(`/${id}/`));
        })
    }
}
```

When the promise is resolved, `redux-promise-middleware`
generates a 'GET_ITEM_FINISHED' action for me. So, in my reducer,
I just put the data I got from server into state:

```
...
case 'GET_ITEM_FINISHED':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        item: action.payload.item
    });
...
```

(The code above had evolved a few dozen of trial-and-error iterations, so it's not clean. I know, it could be prettier, sorry about this.)

It seem to work at first glance, but this way fetching data is completely detached from navigation events - and that's bad. Whenever there's a navigation event that happens from any cause other than `getItem` dispatch (e.g. back/forward buttons), there won't be any fetches and necessary state transitions. This means, the approach I've taken is wrong, on the concept level.

I'm sort of stuck thinking of how to do it. My only thought is that the state should be like a cache that can "hit" (have the item data at navigation event's time) or "miss" (don't have it). When I have the data - like in my code above - I can readily display it. When there's a miss, things get hairy - either a reducer or a component would have to dispatch a "GET_ITEM" action, but while this would probably work, it somehow feels like a bad idea.

Basically, all I want is that red thin "loading" line when navigation's within my UI, but also proper handling of back/forward buttons (or whatever may change location). When user navigates directly to the page (full page load), the backend will make data available in HTML it serves, as store's `preloadedState`.

What I need is a high-level idea/overview of how such things are generally done properly. Or a pointer to any library that implements such idea, if there is anything readily available.